# Can not start openvpn service after a make install

Tags: openvpn, service, debian-wheezy

Quite a specific problem I've been trying to tackle over the last few days and I'm now stuck. Here goes...

I need to run openvpn and the config supplied to me requires openvpn 2.3 or higher but the repos (Armbian / wheezy) only install 2.2.1 so initially I ran a make install of a tarball for the correct version.

Openvpn therefore works great when started in the foreground because it runs the 2.3 version. However, it won't allow me to start the daemon because it is still trying to start openvpn 2.2.1 as the service even though I have installed 2.3.

How is this happening? Will there be two versions of openvpn installed (one from the repos and one from the make install) or is there a config option I am missing?

Many thanks

Comment: It sounds like you should uninstall the 2.2.1 package.  You may have to reinstall from the tarball afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Make a .deb package from v2.3, or download the newer version from debian repositories. There is a backport repo exactly for upgrading individual packages.

```
$ echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-backports.list
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -t wheezy-backports openvpn
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, sort of intuited the answer.

The repo install was in /usr/sbin while my make-install version went into /usr/local/sbin.

I renamed /usr/sbin/openvpn to /usr/sbin/openvpn221.old then created a sym-link pointing to the make install version and now the daemon starts properly.

Comment: it's not the "debian way". When you get upgrade for openvpn it will simply overwrite your symlink.